# How to handle ProblemDetails response from API in .NET MAUI app

Tags: c#, methods, maui, api-design

I am developing a .NET MAUI app using this excellent reference app produced by Microsoft (h/t Michael Stonis):

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eshop-mobile-client

I highly recommend this reference app and its PDF guide for new .NET MAUI programmers (sorry for the auto-download on the MSFT site):

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/e-book/maui/pdf

In it, there is a RequestProvider service that handles the Get/Put/Post/Delete methods that interact with the API, very handy. However, it looks like the methods can only accept or return a single TResult - here is the PutAsync method:

```
public async Task<TResult> PutAsync<TResult>(string uri, TResult data, string token = "", string header = "")
{
    HttpClient httpClient = GetOrCreateHttpClient(token);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
    {
        RequestProvider.AddHeaderParameter(httpClient, header);
    }

    var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data));
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PutAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

    await RequestProvider.HandleResponse(response).ConfigureAwait(false);
    TResult result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TResult>();

    return result;
}
```

Here is my call into this method. 'profile' is a MyProfileClass object to be updated in the API:

```
var response = await _requestProvider.PutAsync(uri, profile, authToken);
```

The response variable is of MyProfileClass type in this case. But if there is a validation or other error in my API, I respond back with an ObjectResult of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ProblemDetails.  Here is my API code that sends it back:

```
return Problem("Error: " + ex.Message, null, 400, "Error Updating Profile");
```

So I want to capture the error message and pass it back from the PutAsync method to throw up an alert to show the user what the problem is. I built a ProblemDetailsWithErrors class to hold this type of result:

```
public class ProblemDetailsWithErrors
{
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string TraceId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is the PutAsync method as it's designed only returns a TResult object. I'm not an expert with C#, but is there a way to return the ProblemDetailsWithErrors object instead of MyProfileClass from PutAsync? Or maybe a way to return both? Maybe it's a simple change to the PutAsync method... any ideas?

Comment: why don't you throw an exception?  That's what the C# exception mechanism was designed for

Comment: but more generally, yes C# supports this.  See the duplicate link

Comment: OK thanks Jason -- I thought there was a way to do it, but I am not familiar with <TResult>.  So would the PutAsync method look like this then?  public async (Task<TResult>,Task<ProblemDetailsWithErrors>) PutAsync<TResult>(...)?  I'm not sure what you mean by throwing an exception -- I don't want to crash the program if there's an API message, just want to show it to the user.

Comment: throwing an exception is really the "correct" way to do this.  I very rarely see anyone using multiple return values

Comment: OK, can you show me an example of what you mean please, and I'll test it and mark as the answer if it works.

Comment: Not multiple results but a wrapper. Have a look into Ardalis/Result on github (not affiliated) as an example.

Comment: make `ProblemDetailsWithErrors` inherit from `System.Exception` and then `throw new ProblemDetailsWithErrors(...)` when you have an error.  The calling method will then use `try/catch` to catch the exception and handle it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions

Comment: Ah, OK so you are essentially 'crashing' the PutAsync method in a controlled way, passing back to the calling routine the error message from the API. Brilliant - you are smarter than I.  :-) 45 years programming and still learning.  Should I rephrase the question above so others can see this, or leave it closed as a duplicate?

Comment: You might consider return a tuple of (TData, Error). We should avoid throwing exception when possible to avoid overhead

Comment: @Jason, it worked like a charm. There is a HandleReponse() method already available, I just needed to add my custom handing of a ProblemDetails response. Thanks for helping me think outside the box. Question reworded for reconsideration to add answer.